How tiling is processed when passing a geometry file to an image in GEE
In ee.reduceRegions, a geometry file is passed as an argument while in ee.sampleRegions, a FeatureCollection is passed. In both of these functions, assuming that an ImageCollection is loaded without clipping, does the whole image gets chunked and processed into tiles or does the algorithms firsh fetches the tiles from the image that only overlap with the passed geometry argument (ee.reduceRegions) or FeatureCollection (ee.sampleRegions) before performing any further computations?

Both reduceRegions() and sampleRegions() take a collection argument of type ee.FeatureCollection. Maybe you are mixing reduceRegions() up with reduceRegion(), which do take a geometry argument of type ee.Geometry?
All of the above are methods on ee.Image, not ee.ImageCollection. Only pixels within the collection or geometry argument gets reduced/sampled.
